# How to change the action part of the form element with ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, forms

The `form` element on my page created with ASP.NET looks as such (if I do "View page source" from a web browser):

```
< form method="post" 
       action="Page.aspx?lang=en-US&amp;pp=10&amp;bi=10" 
       id="ctl01" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

How do I access that form element? I need to remove `&amp;pp=10&amp;bi=10` part from the `action` element?

Comment: do you want to access this in javascript?

Comment: So you have *some code* that is generating some HTML and you want to change the HTML that is being generated? It is really hard to say how to do that without seeing the *some code*. ASP.NET has various different ways to do it (WebForms (shudder) and MVC work completely differently).

Comment: @JørnSchou-Rode: I'm not exactly sure how the answer for that post would work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

if you just have one form on the page then try this in your javascript

```
alert(document.forms[0].action);
```

to change the action just do it like this

```
var actionPath = document.forms[0].action;
// your logic to remove unwanted string with the help of string functions in JS
document.forms[0].action = actionPath;
```

In case you know what is the name of your form then access it like this.

```
document.forms['YOUR_FORM_NAME'].action
```

or you can access it with the client id as well if you want consiering your form 
have runat="server with it

```
document.getElementById(....)// Client Id of the form control
```

Comment: No, I need this from code-behind and not Java Script/